# How would i interact between webserver and android application based on GPS locations?

Tags: java, android, database, gps, webserver

I want to develop an application for android that will enable user1 to input locations. 
and then based on a user2 location that user2 locations will update.

What would be the best way to store this data, holding it on a server?

then what would be the best way for the user2 list of locations to be updated. Would the server take the friends gps location and then based on a certain radius return a list of locations from user1.

This should be able to work for multiple users. Do you guys have any idea's (or is my idea ok).

How would i go about doing this programmatically, i mean how would i interact with server and the android application.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to keep the bulk of the data on the web server and only transferring the data that you require on the mobile phone in order not to overload the little precious memory that the phone has.  The communication can be carried out using SOAP messages which is sort of the standard way or you can also try REST web services.